# C++ reading an output file which should already exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

How do prompt the user to enter the name of the output file and IF not found retry?

Every time this happens it just creates the output file; which i dont want i only want it to read the output file.

```
do{
cout <<"Type the name of the output file which will hold the simulation             results:\n";
cin >> nameoutputfile;
fileout.open(nameoutputfile);

if (fileout.fail())
{
cout << "ERROR: File "<< nameoutputfile <<" could not be opened\n";
tries[1]++;
}
if (tries[1] == trylimit)
{
cout << "ERROR: You exceeded maximum number of tries allowed\n";
cout << "while entering the input file name";
return 2;
}
}while(fileout.fail());
```

This is what the output should be

```
outputReadOnly.txt   
ERROR: File outputReadOnly.txt could not be opened    
Type the name of the output file which will hold the simulation results:  
outputReadOnly.txt  
ERROR: File outputReadOnly.txt could not be opened  
Type the name of the output file which will hold the simulation results:  
outputReadOnlyt.txt  
ERROR: You exceeded maximum number of tries allowed  
while entering the output file name
```

Comment: What type is your fileout object?

Comment: just a file can be anything but has to exist

Comment: I mean how do you initialize the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `ofstream fileout;` which overwrites existing file by default. To achieve desired behavior you could use `fstream` and specify both `in | out` flags:

```
fstream fileout;
do{
  // Other code skipped for simplicity
  fileout.open(nameoutputfile, ios_base::in|ios_base::out);
  // ...
}while(fileout.fail());
```

This is the default flags used by `fstream.open`, so you can just write:

```
fileout.open(nameoutputfile);
```

Comment: didnt understand but what im trying to do is to make sure that the file is not created but shoudl already exist

Comment: @johnsmith Yes, I see. Declare your stream as `fstream fileout`.

Comment: ok but what do i do do so if the file doesnt exist it re-prompts

Comment: is it possible u can write the code to replicate the output